# How should CLLocationManager status be checked in locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization before loading an iOS view?

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, cllocationmanager, cllocation

Since iOS 16/Xcode 14, I get this error:

*This method can cause UI unresponsiveness if invoked on the main thread. Instead, consider waiting for the -locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization: callback and checking authorizationStatus first."?*

I am observing scrolling freezes and long press freezes.

How should what Apple is suggesting be done?

This is my current code segment

```
     /In ViewDidLoad
      if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
        let authorizationStatus: CLAuthorizationStatus
        if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            authorizationStatus = locationManager.authorizationStatus
        } else {
            authorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        }

        switch authorizationStatus {
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
           locationManager.delegate = self                
           locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
           locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()               
           self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
           self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
           self.locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
           //////here data loading happens too////////////
        case .notDetermined:
        case .restricted:
        case .denied:
        @unknown default:
            print("Location services are not enabled")
     }

    /outside ViewDidLoad
     func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])   { 
     ///location database related stuff
     }
```

I tried async/await as suggested here, but it didn't fix the issue. https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714467

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LocationManager's `authorizationStatus` is designed be used when `CLLocationManager`  delegate indicates that there has been a change in your apps authorisation to use location services.

The system calls the `CLLocationManager` delegate method `locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ :)` when  the app’s authorisation status changes. This could be for user-initiated changes or when the user changes permissions after you request `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization()`.  It will also call the delegate method whenever you create a new `CLLocationManager` instance, so it will prompt you to check the value when first run.

When the delegate method is called you should get the value from the `authorizationStatus` property and store it.  If the status is then changed (manually or in response to system usage prompts) it will be called again and you should update your stored value; if not the value you have saved remains valid and there is no need to request it from your `viewDidLoad`.

EDIT to address comment...

You shouldn't be running the location code in `viewDidLoad` - this should be initiated from the delegate when you get an updated location. In viewDidLoad initiate the locations services, eg. by calling this :

```
//struct/class-level properties
var locationManager: CLLocationManager
var authStatus = CLAuthorizationStatus.notDetermined

func startLocationServices() {
   locationManager = CLLocationManager()
   locationManager.delegate = self
   if authStatus == .notDetermined {
      locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
   }
   locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
   }
```

Then action location information with the `CLLocationManagerDelegate`

```
extension HomeVC: CLLocationManagerDelegate {
   func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {
      authStatus = manager.authorizationStatus
      // you could use a `didSet` on `authStatus` to react to changes
   }
   
   func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
      if let newLocation = locations.first {
         process(newLocation)
      }
   }
}
```

and then in the `process(_:)` do what you were trying to do in `viewDidLoad`

Comment: so where would you do this? In App Delegate? The thing is, I only want the viewDidLoad code to run if the status is actually `requestWhenInUseAuthorization()` or `requestAlwaysAuthorization()`